# Unable to automate (AutoIT) in Ruby because of Watir error

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver, autoit

I've tried a few times now to run a Watir browser and then use the AutoIt ruby library (au3) to access a right click context menu but it wasn't working, turns out the au3 library is disappearing for some reason (I'm a little new to Ruby but when I require it again after the browser opens it comes back `false` for some reason:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "au3"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port 9515
[4868:5640:1025/104947:ERROR:textfield.h(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x449008c8 url="about:blank" title="about:blank">
<to "https://github.com/lmmx/watir-paper-scanner/blob/master/bookworm.rb"
[WARNING:..\..\..\..\flash\platform\pepper\pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
=> "https://github.com/lmmx/watir-paper-scanner/blob/master/bookworm.rb"
irb(main):005:0> require "au3"
=> false
irb(main):006:0>
```

I'm guessing that whatever's `SANDBOXED` is crucial to running au3? The browser still works fine... Will try and update the watir-related things, but I only installed it a week or 2 so it shouldn't be out of date already - anyone help me fix it?

Comment: The second `require 'au3'` returns false because it is already loaded (in the first line). This is expected - see the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require).

Comment: ohhh of course! v sorry :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's returning false is because you have already used

```
require "au3"
```

on the top line of your code, so when you require it again it's already there.

Comment: Yeah, some part of the flash player seems to crash and the [4868:5640:1025/104947:ERROR:textfield.h(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED error is still for reasons unknown, even with the new driver, hope that they won't be important...